# Adding a minus button in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, button

I am creating a simple maths APPLICATION using android studio. I want to add a minus sign from a button. I have the following XML code for the butoon.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_minus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/Bottom_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/button_padding"
        android:text="@string/minus"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Also I have this code in my java class.

```
    btn_minus= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
    btn_minus.setOnClickListener(this);
```

This button is not working. Any suggestion guys?

```
     public void onClick(View view)
{

    //button clicked
    if(view.getId()==R.id.enter){
        //enter button
        String answerContent = answerTxt.getText().toString();
        if(!answerContent.endsWith("?"))
        {
            //we have an answer}
            int enteredAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answerContent.substring(2));
            int exScore = getScore();

            if(enteredAnswer==answer){
                //correct
                scoreTxt.setText("Score: "+(exScore+1));
                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.correct);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                //incorrect
                scoreTxt.setText("Score: 0");
                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            chooseQuestion();
        }}
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.clear){
        //clear button
        answerTxt.setText("= ?");
    }
    else {
        //number button
        response.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        if(answerTxt.getText().toString().endsWith("?"))
            answerTxt.setText("= "+enteredNum);
        else
            answerTxt.append(""+enteredNum);
    }
}
```

This is the logcat for the error i get.

```
     --------- beginning of crash
     02-23 13:49:53.586    3996-3996/com.example.administrator.braintraininggame E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.administrator.braintraininggame, PID: 3996
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.administrator.braintraininggame.PlayGame.onClick(PlayGame.java:459)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: please show Your onClick method...

Comment: It should work unless you are not trying to catch the onclick event on the callback of "this"

Comment: show onclickevent...

Comment: yup I'm having the problems with on click event. I have added it above with the rest of the code .

Comment: and what is not working? is it just doing absolutely nothing or did You get an error? And do You have the @Override annotaion for Your onClick?

Comment: I do have the override annotation. The app crashes on pressing the minus button.

Comment: aha...ok now wer´re coming near. Then,please post the logcat output....

Comment: I've just added the logcat output with the rest of the code

Comment: what is in line 459 in Your playGame() class?

Comment: int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());    This is line 459

Comment: do You really want to call getTag() not getText()? And if You want getTag(), where do You have set the Tag?

Comment: oh sorry forgot to add. Now added this to the xml "android:tag="-". Still doesn't work

Comment: do You set a minus sign as a tag?

Comment: ok, so that maybe the cause: first of all, if You set "-", You can´t parse it into integer, like You did with int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());...second: You are trying to get the tag of view not of Your button. Logically, it´s the same, but it isn´t. If You want to get the tag, then You have to call btn_minus.getTag().toString(). But also, parsing integer from a minus sign will crash....

Comment: Do i have to set anything else?

Comment: I don´t know what You really want, but I guess You want to get the number that is entered by the user. So You have to do: yourEditTextView.getText().toString().... and that You can parse if it is a number.....

Answer (score 0):

Minus is not an Integer and it will crash here while parsing it as Integer

It would be best if you just add this code:

```
else if(view.getId()==R.id.btn_minus){
    //minus button
    // substract the value
}
```

Comment: hmm. The problem is that in my app sometimes i get negative answers like 5-9=-4. So i want the user to be able to enter -4

Comment: Yes, but your logic is flawed in this. As on most calculators, adding a minus value can be done like this: put a number and then click +/- key (which you lack) or click minus sign, then click number and then click equals to get a minus number.